# Depth images dont get saved

Tags: rendering, depth-map

I render multiple frames in blender, and if not the frames also, I at least want to save the depth maps, as an image. As can be seen in the screenshot I have attached, I have added a 'File Output' node that specifies that path to save the depth images.  But during rendering, only the frames get saved.
In the output properties, I set the output path for the frames to be saved.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: The path to save should be the path on the file node. The file node works independently from the output set in the properties editor settings

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Out of curiosity though, I havent explicitly mentioned a 'file output' node for the frames, but blender seems to understand that the frames have to be saved at the path mentioned in 'output properties'.  How is this possible?

Comment: The two outputs work independently. If you press render animation,  blender will render and save to the path specified in the output properties and also in the path specified by the file node. In this case there is no "composite" node so you should be getting an empty frame in the path specified in the output settings in the properties window.

Comment: No I dont.  As mentioned earlier, the frames are properly saved in the path specified in output props. It is the depth maps folder that remains empty.

Comment: Did you specify a file name (not just a path) for the output node?

Comment: for the depth maps, in the 'file output' node only a folder name.  Even for frames, under output props Ive mentioned only a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just render pass. It should work as you described.
Possible reasons why it doesn't:

- you don't have enabled Output *Properties > Postprocessing > Pipeline* > **Compositor**
- or you don't have mark checkbox on top row of *Compositor Editor* > **Use Nodes**
- or if you rendered only single image - these are not saved automatically (without add-on)

---

According to your screen, should be rendered only *Depth* pass.
To render and save final render (*Composite* node if enabled) and Depth pass (*File Output* node) at the same time on *Render Animation* action - node tree should look like this (for example):

[image]

Note: *Composite* node can be also replaced *File Output* node. Benefit is not only separate output file, but you can also specify different file format or directory.

Comment: In your answer " To save and render both at the same time", do you mean save and render depth image or frames? I need to only save the depth maps, or both of them if it isnt too much work.  Also, in the image above, I see that the 'composite' block you've added is connected to 'Image', and not depth. So how will that help save depth images? Finally, in the 'View layer properties -> passes -> data", I have checked only Z, not both Z and combined.  Is that alright?

Comment: Worked!! thks a lot....

Comment: I edited a bit the text formulation, so now I'm not sure if you have any questions ... and  what worked for you :) but great you solved it :)